# Facebook like count decreases after logout from facebook and after page refresh

Tags: facebook-like

Whenever I like a page on my website, the like count increases. But when I refresh that page, the like count decreases by 1 count. And when I login and logout from the my facebook account that is  used for like count, the like count decreases.

I have copied the code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Pls help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is how it works from facebook. I have observed this behavior also, the like button not reflecting the right number. I dont think there is anything a third party can do about it.